# Get "Brand" Object on a Product Page in a Bigcommerce Stencil Theme

Tags: bigcommerce

I am developing a Bigcommerce theme on the Stencil framework and want to display all of a brand's products on a single-product page. So, if I am viewing Product A of a particular brand, I want to also display information for Product B, Product C, etc. on that same page. I tried adding the following front-matter to the product.html page under the assumption I could get the object, but I still can't access the brand object.

```
---
brand:
    products:
        limit: {{theme_settings.brandpage_products_per_page}}
---
```

If I add {{json brand.products }} to the html, there is no data. Is this possible from within a Product page/context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The brand object can only be modified with frontmatter from the brand page. It is not currently possible to pull in the products for a given brand while on the product details page.

Please see the documentation on Global invocations to see what you can pull into any page with frontmatter: https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/front-matter-variables#Front-ref-global